# Quick Sort - Median-of-Three pivot selection - Some elements out of order

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, quicksort, median

I have implemented to the best of my abilities the quick sort algorithm from my textbook with the median-of-three pivot selectin function - Data abstraction and problem solving, Walls and Mirrors 7th ed. It is partially working - except, the results of the elements in the array are not all in correct ascending order. For some reason after a certain sequence of numbers are placed in correct order suddenly some ints will be out order in thier own interval it seems and then it will revert to continue afterwards in correct ascending order and then repeats with some ints out of order again. I have adhered to the textbook and I have searched many other solutions and noticed some subtle differences (e.g., my pivot selection function takes 3 parameters whereas all the others I have seen take two). I have attempted to figure it out to no avail, I think it is something minor logically I cannot seem to infer from the pseudo-code in the text.

```
template<typename ItemType>
void sortFirstMiddleLast(ItemType theArray[], int first, int middle, int last) {

    ItemType temp, temp2, temp3;

    if (theArray[first] > theArray[middle]) {

        temp = theArray[first];
        theArray[first] = theArray[middle];
        theArray[middle] = temp;

    }
    if (theArray[middle] > theArray[last]) {

        temp2 = theArray[last];
        theArray[last] = theArray[middle];
        theArray[middle] = temp2;
    }
    if (theArray[first] > theArray[middle]) {

        temp3 = theArray[first];
        theArray[first] = theArray[middle];
        theArray[middle] = temp3;

    }
}
```

```
template<typename ItemType>
int partition(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last)
{
    ItemType temp;

    //Choose pivot and reposition it
    int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;

    sortFirstMiddleLast(theArray, first, mid, last);

    //Interchange
    temp = theArray[last - 1];
    theArray[last - 1] = theArray[mid];
    theArray[mid] = temp;

    int pivotIndex = last - 1;
    ItemType pivot = theArray[pivotIndex];

    //Determine the regions S sub 1 and S sub 2
    int indexFromLeft = first + 1;
    int indexFromRight = last - 2;


    bool done = false;

    while (!done) {

        //locate first entry on left that is >= pivot
        while (theArray[indexFromLeft] < pivot)
            indexFromLeft = indexFromLeft + 1;
        //locate first entry on right that is <= pivot 
        while (theArray[indexFromRight] > pivot)
            indexFromRight = indexFromRight - 1;
        //now indexFromLeft has a new index subscript and indexFromRight has a new index subscript
        //compare the two indexes 
        if (indexFromLeft < indexFromRight) {

            ItemType temp2 = theArray[indexFromRight];
            theArray[indexFromRight] = theArray[indexFromLeft];
            theArray[indexFromLeft] = temp2;
            indexFromLeft = indexFromLeft + 1;
            indexFromRight = indexFromRight - 1;

        }
        else
            done = true;
    }
    //Place pivot in proper position between Ssub1 and Ssub2 and mark its new location
    pivot = theArray[pivotIndex];
    theArray[pivotIndex] = theArray[indexFromLeft];
    theArray[indexFromLeft] = pivot;
    pivotIndex = indexFromLeft;

    return pivotIndex;

}
```

```
template<typename ItemType>
void quickSort(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last) {
    //sift out small arrays 

    int n = last - first + 1;

    if ( n < MIN_SIZE){//array is of size < 10 so use insertion sort

        insertionSort(theArray, n);

    }
    else {
        //Make the partition : S1 | Pivot | S2
        int pivotIndex = partition(theArray, first, last);

        //Sort subarrays S1 and S2
        quickSort(theArray, first, pivotIndex - 1);
        quickSort(theArray, pivotIndex + 1, last);

    }

}
```

```
const int RAND_NUMSIZE = 51; // for quick sort array size (random number gen 1-50)
const int MIN_SIZE = 10;//specify size of smallest array to use quick sort

int main()
{
int array5[RAND_NUMSIZE] = { 50, 41, 45, 43, 48, 40, 47, 42, 46, 49, 44, 39, 31, 37, 35, 33, 32, 38, 33, 34, 30, 36, 21, 29, 20, 22, 28, 23, 27, 24, 26, 25, 19, 13, 18, 14, 17, 15, 16, 12, 10, 11, 7, 8, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 5 }

    std::cout << "\nThe quick sort array before sorting: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < RAND_NUMSIZE; i++) {
        std::cout << array5[i] << ' ';
    }
    //call quick sort
    quickSort(array5, 0, RAND_NUMSIZE - 1);
    std::cout << "\nThe quick sort array after sorting: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < RAND_NUMSIZE; i++) {
        std::cout << array5[i] << ' ';
    }
```

Image link displaying the results I am talking about:

[quickSort console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMQDI.jpg)

Comment: *except, the results of the elements in the array are not all in correct ascending order.* -- That's one mighty big *except*.  Your sort isn't sorting.  *I have attempted to figure it out to no avail,* -- Use the debugger that comes with your compiler, single-step through the program until you see the program has done something unexpected.

Comment: Second, sort 5 or 6 numbers, not 51 numbers.  If you can't sort 5 or 6 numbers, you aren't going to sort 51 numbers.  Sorting so many numbers will have you lose track of what is happening.  Find out, with the smallest number of elements, what sequence causes the error.  Then focus on that smaller sequence of values.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Paul, I reduced the array to ~10 elements and it is the same results...the first several numbers are in correct order and then an out of order int sequence happens..I am thinking I must do a for loop to iterate over the array and nest the if clauses within it inside my sortFirstMiddleLast function.

Comment: To see what is the issue, choose the first number in the array as the pivot instead of median-of-three.  Does the sort work when you do that?  If so, then the basics of the quicksort are ok, and your pivot-choosing strategy is not right.  If the sort doesn't work when you simply choose the first value as the pivot, then it is your sorting routine that is faulty (and there are plenty of quicksort implementations written in C++ to use as a reference).

Comment: Figured it out...the error was occuring in my quicksort function..my base case was not implemented as it should and so it was attempting to still use recursion for array sizes it would not work on. I corrected it to sort subarrays less than 4 in size without partitioning function or quick sort recursion by just using sortFirstMiddleLast and it works. Should I answere my own question or delete it? This is my first time doing this and I noticed already my rep is being faulted.

Comment: I think you can leave the question as-is.  The title of the thread seems ok (not like "why doesn't my program work?").

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem in your `quickSort()` here:

```
if (n < MIN_SIZE) { //array is of size < 10 so use insertion sort
    insertionSort(theArray, n);
}
```

When you have a small partition you are **always** insertion sorting the first `n` elements of `theArray`.

You actually want to sort the range from `first` to `last`. You can do that by passing a pointer to `theArray[first]` and the small partition size like this:

```
if (n < MIN_SIZE) { //array is of size < 10 so use insertion sort
    insertionSort(theArray + first, n);
}
```

Of course, you want to be sure your insertion sort is correct as well...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved once I corrected the implementation of my base case in the quick sort function, instead of using insertion sort, I called sortFirstMiddleLast after setting the const value of MIN_SIZE to 4, thus using the pivot selection function to sort 3 entries instead of causing logic error by attempting to use partitioning and recursion for small subarrays..

```
template<typename ItemType>
void quickSort(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last) {
    //relegate out small arrays 

    int n = last - first + 1;//index range of elements to consider

    int middle = first + (last - first) / 2;

    if ( n < MIN_SIZE){//array is of size < 4 so no partition or quick sort

        sortFirstMiddleLast(theArray, first, middle, last);//base case

    }
    else {
        //Make the partition : S1 | Pivot | S2
        int pivotIndex = partition(theArray, first, last);

        //Sort subarrays S1 and S2
        quickSort(theArray, first, pivotIndex - 1);
        quickSort(theArray, pivotIndex + 1, last);

    }


}
```